# Há algo de errado no meu código?

Tags: python

Fiz um código Python que aparenta estar funcionando corretamente.
Mas por motivos de melhorias de código quero saber se há uma forma de aumentar a performance dele
ou se algo que estou fazendo está errado.
Segue o código.

```
def quadrado(numero):
    """Encontra o quadrado"""
    return numero ** 2


def cubo(numero):
    """Encontra o cubo"""
    return f'O cubo de {numero} é igual a: {numero ** 3}'


print("Olá, seja bem-vindo")
print("Primeiramento precisaremos de seu nome, insira-o logo abaixo!")

nome = input()

print(f"Olá, {nome}")
print(' ')
print("Estamos quase lá, para utilizar o programa digite .cubo para achar o cubo de qualquer número que deseje")
print("Ou apenas digite .quadrado para achar o quadrado de qualquer número que deseje")
comando = input()
comando2 = '.denovo'

if comando == '.cubo':
    while comando2 == '.denovo':
        print("Insira um inteiro para que seja encontrado o cubo do mesmo!")
        num_cubo = int(input())
        print(cubo(num_cubo))
        print(' ')
        print('Deseja calcular o cubo de mais um número? Caso a resposta seja sim digite .denovo')
        print(' ')
        print('Caso contrário apenas aperte ENTER para fechar a aplicação')
        comando2 = input()
elif comando == '.quadrado':
    while comando2 == '.denovo':
        print("Insira um inteiro para que seja encontrado o quadrado do mesmo!")
        num_cubo = int(input())
        print(quadrado(num_cubo))
        print(' ')
        print('Deseja calcular o quadrado de mais um número? Caso a resposta seja sim digite .denovo')
        print(' ')
        print('Caso contrário apenas aperte ENTER para fechar a aplicação')
        comando2 = input()
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Código muito bacana, para melhorar ao invés de usar *print('')* use *\n* para saltar linha

if comando == '.cubo':
while comando2 == '.denovo':
print("Insira um inteiro para que seja encontrado o cubo do mesmo!")
num_cubo = int(input())
print(cubo(num_cubo))
// Pulou Linha com \n
print('\nDeseja calcular o cubo de mais um número? Caso a resposta seja sim digite .denovo\n')
// Pulou Linha com \n

```
    print('Caso contrário apenas aperte ENTER para fechar a aplicação')
    comando2 = input()
```